# Can Inno Setup send key and mouse presses, if not, how can this be done using an Installer?

Tags: automation, inno-setup, autohotkey, nsis

I'm a newbie to both [Microsoft Windows] installers and [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) but I need to know if Inno Setup (or an equivalent) can be used automate the input to a GUI-based windows program, during install, e.g. by clicking on a menu and selecting a sub-item, for instance?

I'm aware of [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit) and [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), as well as [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net), however Inno Setup comes highly recommended as a software packager/installer, and I also like the idea of learning a little Pascal programming, into the bargain ;)

Any ideas or thoughts are most welcome :-)

Comment: If you want to control InnoSetup installer, just do it. It's a standard windows application (usually running elevated, what shouldn't be a problem for GUI automation programs you've mentioned). If you're going to control some application from installer, then you're either hacker or you're doing something wrong :-) In latter case please elaborate what is your intention for doing so, so we can refine your design.

Comment: @TLama - no hacking, just need to start/configure an application with no command line/configuration file/registry entries. Normally, the user would start the application manually, we're just trying to aid the non-technical user. Ideally, it would great if the application's GUI could be called silently (yes, it does sound hack-ish, I know), this application just serves as a 'dongle' to another application, but needs to be in a running and configured state before the main application is started up. I may be looking at this wrong, and need to design a separate automation after install (???)

Comment: You can start an AutoIt script from Inno if you want.  But as TLama said this sort of thing is usually a last resort -- it's far better to find proper settings locations or parameters to automate installation of repackaged apps.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Deanna, the [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is the best for simulating user input you can get. In the following script I've shown how to simulate mouse clicks on the absolute screen position (in pixels). As an example I'm trying to show Inno Setup's about box through the *Help / About Inno Setup* menu item (if you would have the same screen settings as me and have the Inno Setup IDE maximized, it may even hit that menu item. So here's just the mouse part (and only limited functionality you can get). Take it rather as a proof, that it's possible to simulate user input from Inno Setup:

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[code]
const
  SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
  SM_CYSCREEN = 1;
  INPUT_MOUSE = 0;
  MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = $0001;
  MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = $0002;
  MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = $0004;
  MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = $0008;
  MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = $0010;
  MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = $0020;
  MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = $0040;
  MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = $4000;
  MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = $8000;
type
  TMouseInput = record
    Itype: DWORD;    
    dx: Longint;
    dy: Longint;
    mouseData: DWORD;
    dwFlags: DWORD;
    time: DWORD;
    dwExtraInfo: DWORD;
  end;

function GetSystemMetrics(nIndex: Integer): Integer;
  external 'GetSystemMetrics@user32.dll stdcall';
function SendMouseInput(nInputs: UINT; pInputs: TMouseInput;
  cbSize: Integer): UINT; 
  external 'SendInput@user32.dll stdcall';

function SendMouseClick(Button: TMouseButton; X, Y: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Flags: DWORD;
  Input: TMouseInput;
  ScreenWidth: Integer;
  ScreenHeight: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  Flags := MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK or MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
  ScreenWidth := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
  ScreenHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

  Input.Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
  Input.dx := Round((X * 65536) / ScreenWidth);
  Input.dy := Round((Y * 65536) / ScreenHeight);
  case Button of
    mbLeft: Input.dwFlags := Flags or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    mbRight: Input.dwFlags := Flags or MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
    mbMiddle: Input.dwFlags := Flags or MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN;
  end;  
  Result := SendMouseInput(1, Input, SizeOf(Input)) = 1;

  if Result then
  begin
    Input.Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.dx := Round((X * 65536) / ScreenWidth);
    Input.dy := Round((Y * 65536) / ScreenHeight);
    case Button of
      mbLeft: Input.dwFlags := Flags or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
      mbRight: Input.dwFlags := Flags or MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
      mbMiddle: Input.dwFlags := Flags or MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP;
    end;    
    Result := SendMouseInput(1, Input, SizeOf(Input)) = 1;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  if MsgBox('Are you sure you want to let the installer click ' +
    'somewhere on your screen ? TLama warned you :-)', mbConfirmation, 
    MB_YESNO) = IDYES then
  begin
    if not SendMouseClick(mbLeft, 242, 31) then 
      MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError), mbError, mb_Ok);
    if not SendMouseClick(mbLeft, 382, 263) then 
      MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError), mbError, mb_Ok);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, really, my only issue with this is that you mention absolute pixel locations, what I think I really I need is something more declarative, i.e. click menu X, select option Y, so I don't have to be concerned with where the item actually physically is on the screen. As I said, I'm new to installers in general, so maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. I really wanted an all-in-one tool, but maybe I should use Inno Setup solely for the software install, and something like AutoIt for my UI automation. What say you and @Deanna?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any library, which would be shipped as standalone (so we could import it into the InnoSetup) and which would be able to do what you want. From the Windows point of view it would be very big task to develop this sort of automation software. But back to your first comment. You've said you need to configure certain application, so I assume this application saves a configuration somehow. Can't you e.g. change this config. and ask user to restart it with a message like *Your application config has been updated and my application needs you to restart it.* for instance ?

Comment: You can actually use AutoIt to perform the installation stuff and pack the whole script into an executable.

So it might be best for you just to use AutoIt with its FileInstall function and the Control...-functions. See the documentation of these functions for good examples.
 And AutoIt has got a basic-like code structure, so it's probably the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @Johannes, but can you distribute setup with embedded AutoIt ? I mean, is that legal ?

Comment: That depends on the license of the program you want to repackage... How could I know? ;-) You could let your script extract the setup to your Temp-Folder and run it in background (using WinSetState with @SW_HIDE and then some Control...-Functions to automate the installation) and then perform the further steps like clicking somewhere as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet for this is to use the `SendInput()` API from a DLL that you then call from Inno Setup.
This will allow full control of everything you can do manually in that application.