# How to implement MAKELPARAM for SendMessage function in Inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to make a page in the installer when the setup move's the mouse in the setup window, here is the SendMessage documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx
The problem is I need the MAKELPARAM implementation to set the x,y positions.
Can somebody help me to do that ?

Comment: You should not do that.  Moving the mouse for the user is annoying (especially if it can occur when they're doing something else and your install happens to complete something in the background and then "helpfully" moves the mouse, ruining what they were actually working on).  If you're trying to automate something (eg. a subinstaller), you should use the tools appropriate to that task (eg. running silently and providing the correct command line parameters or response files) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Inno Setup Pascal Script the macros for message parameters according to SDK could be written as:

```
[Code]
type
  LONG_PTR = LongInt;
  LRESULT = LONG_PTR;  
  WPARAM = UINT_PTR;
  LPARAM = LONG_PTR;

function MakeLong(A, B: Word): LongInt;
begin
  Result := A or B shl 16;
end;

function MakeWParam(L, H: Word): WPARAM;
begin
  Result := WPARAM(DWORD(MakeLong(L, H)));
end;

function MakeLParam(L, H: Word): LPARAM;
begin
  Result := LPARAM(DWORD(MakeLong(L, H)));
end;

function MakeLResult(L, H: Word): LRESULT;
begin
  Result := LRESULT(DWORD(MakeLong(L, H)));
end;
```

---

But I would like to suggest you to not use message sending to simulate user's input. I would personally use a more reliable way by using [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. I've made some basic example in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741933/can-inno-setup-send-key-and-mouse-presses-if-not-how-can-this-be-done-using-an/14750678#14750678).